# Include color string in statusline

Tags: vim

I have some function defined as

```
function! myfunc()
    let s = 'hello world'
    return s
endfunction
```

and I can include this in my status line as `statusline=%{myfunc()}`, which nicely prints 'hello world'. I can also color it as `statusline=%#mycolor#%{myfunc()}` where `mycolor` is a color I've defined.

Now I want to color each of the words separately, so I redefine my function as

```
function! myfunc()
    let s = '%#mycolor1#hello %#mycolor2#world'
    return s
endfunction
```

However, when I set this in the status line, the output is simply the literal string `"%#mycolor1#hello %#mycolor2#world"`, whereas I want `hello` to be colored according to `mycolor1` and `world` colored according to `mycolor2`.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this vim utility may partly answer your question:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3383

So it looks like you can't have color changes within your 'myfunc' function.  But you can get color changes by assigning statusline using an exec command, e.g.:

```
:let sl_statement = 'set statusline=%#' . color1highlight .
                 \   '#%{myfunc1()}%#' . color2hl . '#%{myfunc2()}'
:exec sl_statement
```