# Set text color to a string in statusline

Tags: vim

I'll preface by saying that I am using Airline, [plytophogy/vim-virtualenv](https://github.com/plytophogy/vim-virtualenv) plugin and gruvbox as the Airline theme.

I am trying to change the color of some string in the status line to, say, orange.
In my case that is the "@my_env" string that states my current working environment: [image]

Currently, the line in my .vimrc that is responsible for this text is:

```
let g:airline_section_c='%t @%{virtualenv#statusline()}'
```

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994525/include-color-string-in-statusline), I tried to change my .vimrc line to

```
let g:airline_section_c='%t %#orange#@%{virtualenv#statusline()}'
```

which seems to have highlighted the statusline from "@my_env" onwards:
[image: Before]

It seems that using `%#any_color#` or even `%##`by itself produces the same effect.

I have read through all [:h 'statusline'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27statusline%27) and did not seem to find an appropriate solution.

So my question is: Is there a way to set a color for a string in the statusline?

**EDIT**:

The question has been answered [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19661/change-set-color-to-a-string-in-statusline)

It seems that there is no way to change the text color of the screen without changing its entire formatting group (including the background).

Appending `%#airline_c#` to the end of the string to addition fixed the highlighting issue though:

This is what it looks like with

`let g:airline_section_c='%t %#Special#%{virtualenv#statusline()}%#airline_c#'`

[image]
where `Special` is a random highlighting group

Answer (score 0):

In `:help statusline`, in the description of the formatting, you can find:

> ```
>    * -   Set highlight group to User{N}, where {N} is taken from the                                                                                                                                          
>           minwid field, e.g. %1*.  Restore normal highlight with %* or %0*.                                                                                                                                    
>           The difference between User{N} and StatusLine  will be applied                                                                                                                                       
>           to StatusLineNC for the statusline of non-current windows.                                                                                                                                           
>           The number N must be between 1 and 9.  See hl-User1..9
> ```

So if you change:

```
let g:airline_section_c='%t %#orange#@%{virtualenv#statusline()}'
```

into:

```
let g:airline_section_c='%t %#orange#@%{virtualenv#statusline()}%*'
```

It should stop the coloring after the virtualenv.